# Changing the color Column Header in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day! Can the Column Header Color can be changed in Odoo?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good Day I found some solutions to my problem Just create a css file and JavaScript get class name of your Field..

Create first a JavaScript
Example:

```
openerp.your_module_name= function (instance) {
instance.web.list.columns.add('field.your_field_name', 'instance.your_module_name.your_field_name');
instance.your_module_name.your_field_name = instance.web.list.Column.extend({
    _format: function (row_data, options) {
        res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var amount = parseFloat(res);
        return "<font color='#0000CD'>"+amount.toFixed(2)+"</font>";
    }
});};
```

This Javascript I only Found it some Forums this code is to change the font color of some columns.
To Change the Column Header is to Call  the your_field_name define in JavaScript and Just create a CSS File
CSS
Example:

```
.openerp .oe_list_your_field_name{
background-color: #FF3333;}
```

Hope to help with this code :D